# HttpClient URL call fails

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to do a Http POST to an API from a linux machine. But my call to the URL fails with timeout error. I am using httpclient-4.5.8 library for this.
Background: Initially my client server was not whitelisted so I used to get "403-Forbidden" from the URL. But after whitelisting there is timeout error.

```
public void PostMessage() {     
    try {

        final RequestConfig params = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(3000).setSocketTimeout(3000).build();
        httpPost = new HttpPost(getUri());
        log4.debug("URL set up done for "+ httpPost.getURI());
        final StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(getMessage());
        httpPost.setConfig(params);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


        CloseableHttpResponse response = (CloseableHttpResponse) client.execute(httpPost);
        log4.info("Response Code:" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            log4.info("Response Content:" + line);
        }
        } catch (IOException i) {
            log4.info("Error at PostClient.IOException. " + i.getMessage());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log4.info("Error at PostClient.Exception. " + e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Log trace: (Pardon for the masking)

"message":"URL set up done for https://ABCD.com/","logger":"com.tesco.ReceiptClient.PublishClient.ReceiptPostClient:PostMessage"

"message":"CookieSpec selected: default","logger":"org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies:process"

"message":"Auth cache not set in the context","logger":"org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache:process"

"message":"Connection request: [route: {s}->https://ABCD.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]","logger":"org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:requestConnection"

"message":"Connection leased: [id: 1][route: {s}->https://ABCD.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]","logger":"org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:leaseConnection"

"message":"Opening connection {s}->https://ABCD.com:443","logger":"org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec:execute"

"message":"Connecting to ABCD.com/xxx.xx.xx.x:443","logger":"org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:connect"

"message":"Connecting socket to ABCD.com/xxx.xx.xx.x:443 with timeout 3000","logger":"org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory:connectSocket"

"message":"http-outgoing-1: Shutdown connection","logger":"org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingManagedHttpClientConnection:shutdown"

"message":"Connection discarded","logger":"org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ConnectionHolder:abortConnection"

"message":"Connection released: [id: 2][route: {s}->https://ABCD.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]","logger":"org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:releaseConnection"

"message":"Error at PostClient.IOException. Connect to ABCD.com:443 [ABCD.com/xxx.xx.xx.x] failed: connect timed out","logger":"com.tesco.ReceiptClient.PublishClient.ReceiptPostClient:PostMessage"

Comment: Have you tried by setting timeout to some very large values and not 3000?

Comment: maybe the server is broken? or your request is? or the call takes longer than 3 sec? can you prove the server works using a rest client? like postman etc?

Comment: @RahulAgrawal I set both connection and socket timeouts to 30000 now and it waits for 30 seconds, but fails with same error.

Comment: @thst Well the problem is I can test it from any UX client as it's a server machine. But I did try to do wget on the URL and it seems to be failing on the same timeout error. I think I might need to request the URL guys to demo a successful request on to that.

Comment: but the „ux client“ works? Sis you check proxy etc. settings

Comment: locl desktop Firewalls or Antivirus can expose such application specific behaviour

Comment: Well, no problems with the code. Finally turns out the URL was invalid. SMH. Consider this thread closed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is connectivity with the server (telnet/ping).

Normally you will get **Connection time out** error when you don't have any connectivity with server and **Read time out** if the server takes longer time then given by "read-timeout" config.